# How can i create an calculate columns with condition on aggragate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I try to create a max_time columns which in row rsvn 1 will have value of 2 (max of status == 'ss' of rsvn 1) and in row rsvn 2 will have value 6.

How can i do that with 1 row of pandas code

[image: The original df doesn't have max_time column]

Comment: Can you share your code or a runnable example and say what you already test?

Comment: df['test']= df[df.status == 'ss'].groupby(['rsvn','status'])['time'].transform(np.max)
when test this code the row where status == 'f' is all null

Answer (score 1):

```
# Assuming the data is like this:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'rsvn': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2}, 
     'status': {0: 'ss', 1: 'ss', 2: 'f', 3: 'f', 4: 'ss', 5: 'ss', 6: 'f', 7: 'f'}, 
     'time': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8}}
)

# you can recreate the max_time column like this:
max_df = df[df['status'] == 'ss'].groupby('rsvn')['time'].max().rename('max_time').reset_index()
df.merge(max_df, on='rsvn', how = 'left')
```

Comment: Thank you but i only want to get the max time value of status == 'ss'

Comment: the result is null in the row where status == 'f'

Comment: right, as it should be @KhoaVo

Comment: actually i aim to get the value of max_time in the row where status =='f' is  max of ['time'] where status =='ss'

Comment: okay final update @KhoaVo